# Kafka consumer stopped consuming message after producer ack mode change

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a producer and consumer application which works perfectly. My three producers are used ack mode '1' and today I changed one producer ack mode to 'ALL'. Soon after all consumers stopped consuming messages. I can see producers are producing messages to Kafka without an error. But My consumers are not consuming any. I can see following logs in consumer console.

```
Line 1:  2020-06-12 16:28:22|INFO |[o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.info(341)]|[Consumer clientId=consumer-24, groupId=aaa] Revoking previously assigned partitions [xxx]
        Line 2:  2020-06-12 16:28:22|INFO |[o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator.info(336)]|[Consumer clientId=consumer-24, groupId=aaa] (Re-)joining group
        Line 14: 2020-06-12 16:33:02|INFO |[o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator.info(341)]|[Consumer clientId=consumer-24, groupId=aaa] Successfully joined group with generation 502
        Line 17: 2020-06-12 16:33:02|INFO |[o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.info(341)]|[Consumer clientId=consumer-24, groupId=aaa] Setting newly assigned partitions [xxx]
        Line 23: 2020-06-12 16:33:56|INFO |[o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.info(341)]|[Consumer clientId=consumer-24, groupId=aaa] Revoking previously assigned partitions [xxx]
        Line 24: 2020-06-12 16:33:56|INFO |[o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator.info(336)]|[Consumer clientId=consumer-24, groupId=aaa] (Re-)joining group
        Line 28: 2020-06-12 16:38:02|INFO |[o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator.info(341)]|[Consumer clientId=consumer-24, groupId=aaa] Successfully joined group with generation 503
        Line 30: 2020-06-12 16:38:02|INFO |[o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.info(341)]|[Consumer clientId=consumer-24, groupId=aaa] Setting newly assigned partitions [xxx]
        Line 33: 2020-06-12 16:38:56|INFO |[o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.info(341)]|[Consumer clientId=consumer-24, groupId=aaa] Revoking previously assigned partitions [xxx]
        Line 34: 2020-06-12 16:38:56|INFO |[o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator.info(336)]|[Consumer clientId=consumer-24, groupId=aaa] (Re-)joining group
        Line 39: 2020-06-12 16:43:02|INFO |[o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator.info(341)]|[Consumer clientId=consumer-24, groupId=aaa] Successfully joined group with generation 504
        Line 40: 2020-06-12 16:43:02|INFO |[o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.info(341)]|[Consumer clientId=consumer-24, groupId=aaa] Setting newly assigned partitions [xxx]
```

I tried a different consumer with a new groupId and that works fine. But still I can't change my groupId and consumer in the prod.

Comment: Check the status of your topic, are there any under replicated partitions? What's the config of the topic's replication factor and `min.insync.repcicas`?

Comment: min.insync.repcicas=1, topic has 4 partitions. What did you mean under replicated partitions? Where I can find topic's replication factor ?

Comment: to find out replication factor and ISR you can do `$ kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server my-broker:9092 --topic my-topic`

Comment: replication factor is 2

Comment: and this topic has both replicas listed in the ISR column when you run the describe command?

Comment: I don't have access to server to get data. Server access is limited to certain IP's. so not possible to run commands straight. I need to go through server team to get required data. What is the guess you have in mind ?